# Combine multiple queries into one in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I have a dynamic Rails query, wherein I'm passing a parameter and turning it into a array so that each array attribute could be used for the querying.

Here's what I have so far, but it isn't working:

```
def sort_by_networks
  @creators = []
  array = params[:provider_name].split(',')
  array.each do |a|
    @query = User.where("identities.provider = ?", 
    a.downcase).joins(:identities, :roles).all(conditions:{roles:{name: 'Creator'}})
  end
    @creators += @query
end
```

Any workarounds will be appreciated.

Comment: inside the iteration of the array.each call you didn't use the @query anywhere, what is you intention of doing this in the iteration. plz provide much more info about your question, some example may be better.

Answer (score 0):

Hi got it already.

```
@creators = []
array = params[:provider_name].split(',')
array.each do |a|
  @query = User.where("identities.provider = ?", a.downcase).joins(:identities, :roles).all(conditions:{roles:{name: 'Creator'}})
  @creators += @query
end
@creators
```